# Meaning of docker runs the container as root user

Tags: docker

Does `docker runs the container as root user` means the effective UID of the processes started inside the container is the root user **inside** the container? Or the host container process invoked with `docker run` has or may have the effective UID of root **on the host**?

I am not so sure if it is talking inside the container or on the host or if it can be both. I suppose it is specific to inside the container only but if this is not the case, please help understand.

For instance, it is only when the docker daemon runs with the root effective UID, and the container processes on the host also can have the root privilege, hence using root inside the container is the same with giving root privilege to the processes started inside the container?

Answer (score 2):

By default the docker daemon runs with root privileges, which allows among others allows it to perform tasks that require root permissions on the docker host, like for example the exposing of privileged ports, mapping/mounting of file  systems and volumes, and more.

---

That is not a hard requirement though: you can the run the Docker daemon as a non-root user in what is know as "[rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/)".

And in either mode you can use *user namespaces* to re-map the root  user to a less-privileged user on the Docker host, when  the  containers runs  processes that must run as the root user within the container. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

Comment: @mon  And in case it isn't obvious to you from the first paragraph, running with root privs means you can mount the host's /etc inside you container and change the root password or mount /usr/bin and make bash setuid root. There are very good reasons why many institutions don't run Docker on any multi-user systems. Singularity was written at Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory and quickly adopted by other supercomputer centers specifically to have a more secure environment.